# Where do I get the token for the vaulted card information with the BlueSnap Payment API?

Tags: bluesnap

I'm vaulting credit card data on BlueSnap, using the vaulted shopper request. How do I get the token of the vaulted card data? I get an empty body in response to my request..

Answer (score 0):

The BlueSnap token for the vaulted shopper info will be returned in the URL in the location header. For example:
location: https://sandbox.bluesnap.com/services/2/vaulted-shoppers/20848977

In this case, the vaulted-shopper-id (token) is 20848977